# Array filter and map at the same time?

Tags: javascript

I feel like an idiot, but I need to filter my array, and then map those values, but thats O(2N) and it would make more sense to do it all in O(N) but I can't find a stock Array.prototype function

```
array.filter(item => !!item.revenue).map(item => item.revenue)
```

I can always write my own method but it would be best to use the performance optimized Array.prototype ones, if there is one

Comment: paste the code of the two operations, and we'll check how to do it in one way, ok?

Comment: Sounds like you want another method like reduce

Comment: Does it really worth to trade readability with one extra iteration?

Comment: @zerkms sorry man, i rolled it back, was confused

Comment: O(n)  and O(2n) are equivalent... Also you may want to check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators and avoid both map/filter altogether...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "O(n) and O(2n) are equivalent" --- constants still matter. `O(n)` vs `O(1000000n)`: the latter would run ~1million times slower.

Comment: @zerkms it does not sound like neaumusic is concerned about performance, but rather about just number of iteration over sequence... :)

Comment: Don't assume that the prototype methods will be as fast as a simple loop either. `while` loop vs `forEach` is good example

Comment: Both are O(2n). Doing one operation each in two passes or two operations in one pass is O(2n) = O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatMap` covers this use case - filtering and mapping at the same time:

```
arr.flatMap(item => item.revenue || [])
```

Answer (score 6):

How about [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)?

```
arr.reduce((newArr, item) => {
    if (!!item.revenue) {
        newArr.push(item.revenue)
    }
    return newArr
}, []);
```

Comment: dang, i saw reduce but didn't realize you can construct an array, thought only a single variable, thanks

Comment: The downside is that, unlike map, this doesn't preallocate. Because it can't know how many items will be filtered.

Comment: @Oriol "the downside" compared to *what*? You cannot solve the problem with just `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: yea it's not a direct mapping, i need to exclude some

Comment: @zerkms I mean, if almost all items will remain, it might make sense to create an array as big as the initial one, fill it with the desired items (keeping the index in some variable), and then reduce the length.

Comment: This is less clear than filter and map, and I would wager, no more performant.

Comment: Just tested them both on nodejs 6.2.2 (V8 5.0.71.52) and this is around 4x faster than filter and map.

Comment: @DavidConrad nice of you to come back on that with some stats.